# Object clipping - change the view clipping doesn't help

Tags: cinema4d

When I navigate around the viewport my cylinder is clipping, in some angles it even disappears.
It looks clipped in my rendered view as well.
[image: view clipping set to tiny]

Comment: This may not be the best place to ask. To illustrate the point: This year there has been 10 Cinema4D questions. 4 of 10 Has no answers, 6 of them have one unaccepted answer. Most of them very brief comment like answers. Year before this has only 3 questions but one accepted answer. Since this is not ultimately a graphic design question it is sort of understandable why it has no answer. (note graphic and graphics are two different things). Anyway adjust your camera near and far clipping planes. This sis a central concept in how the 3D imager works.